# Allowing boot of Ubuntu on a Acer Aspire v5-531 with UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14 (64-bit) on a Aspire V5-531, preinstalled Win 8. 
In the bios I can flag:

boot mode UEFI, secure boot DISABLE

- in this case the neither installation USB card nor cd rom start

boot mode in Legacy Mode

- I can install Ubuntu 14, but grub doesn't work (yes, I used boot repair, but it doesen't work properly).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolved it this way:

- let boot mode UEFI enabled, secure boot enabled
- in BIOS added the USB boot file of the distribution I want to install as trusted for executing:

My BIOS is Phoenix SecureCore Tiano Setup

- Under `Boot` I flag `Boot Mode UEFI`
- Secure Boot ENABLE
- Under `SECURITY` select: `Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing`
- in `Available File System` I select `fs0:$nameofmyusbkey`
- Select `[EFI]`
- Select `[BOOT]`
- Select `BOOTx64.EFI`
- Give it the name *whateveryouwant* then, using tab, select YES.
- so I go to the Boot option, then put *whateveryouwant* as first in the Boot priority order
- then I was able to start Ubuntu installation in UEFI mode! :)

**WARNING!**

Before I did all this, I freed the space for my partitions under Windows 8. I read so many guide about UEFI and UEFI install (I give advice to do it!), and tried in several ways. That was the only way I was able to do what I wanted.

Comment: perfect thanks.......I had a different model but once reading Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing everything fell into line.....Also if its blacked out simply add a supervisor password and continue :)

Comment: May you post a link to a good EFI guide you found valuable of those you mentioned in your post?

Comment: @FrancescoMM Google mi è stato d'aiuto (5 anni fa)

Comment: @feligiotti Haha, ok, I'll try googling too, today.

Comment: this answer is a saver. merci beacoup!!!