# Unable to install ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop having windows 7

Tags: 14.04

I am having windows 7 installed on my laptop.
I tried to make it dual boot by installing the 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04.01 but at the end of installation it gives an error message.

```
Unable to install.Permission denied.for more details check log at location
c:\users\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log.
```

I was doing the installation using the Live CD but couldn't do it then i tried using boot-able pen-drive but the result was same.

My system configuration is as below.

```
Dell Vostro 3560
with i5-3230M processor @ 2.6 Ghz 4 GB Ram 500GB HDD,1 GB AMD radeon HD 7670M DDR3
OS windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit version.
```

Kindly Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have been using ubuntu from last 4 years and i know the installation procedure.i am sure i have not done anything wrong while installation.Please try to understand the problem and then suggest the solution.

Comment: It looks like you have been trying to use the WUBI install. It does not work with new computers that comes with the UEFI instead of BIOS. Please try complete install by booting from Live DVD/USB. Ubuntu 14.04 won't fit in a CD. If you have UEFI then you will need the 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 for the complete install.

Comment: I have been trying to boot it through Live DVD only,but at the end of installation it delivers a message                                                           c:\users\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log.

Comment: This does not make any sense. If you directly boot Ubuntu from the LiveDVD, then it won't get the error message about wubi log. Boot from the DVD and choose Try Ubuntu without installing. If you get any errors **update your questions above.**

Answer (score 0):

If it's a newer one that uses UEFI, disable secure boot and set it to legacy mode. This should resolve any issues you have, as it'll then act like a BIOS. All Wubi does is add a disk image containing Ubuntu, an "mbr" file containing GRUB, and a boot entry in BCD.

If it uses a BIOS, then perhaps your issue is with the administrator privileges. Give Wubi admin and try again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure is the best way change to _legacy, eufi disable_ That way was to me so problematic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/519610/uefi-catch-22-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-531