# Trying to install Ubuntu to a USB HDD with Windows 8 on internal? Need confirmation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I am trying to make sure that Ubuntu will install correctly and boot from a USB HDD. Windows 8.1 is installed on the primary internal 1TB, this is a 230 GB (after all extra was taken out). If I were to install Ubuntu to this drive, tell my UEFI to boot from USB HDD, and boot with it plugged in, would it ***boot properly?***

Comment: I did like it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/519610/uefi-catch-22-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-531/519619#519619

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it to work. There were some glitches at first, but all was sorted out. I had to do the following:

- Choose "Something Else" Menu
- Install everything to formatted 250GB Drive
- Go through setup process
- Fix GRUB timer and default timeout choice
- Do a bunch of reboots for updating various files and stuff
- Accidental HDD unplug while shutting down
- Hard Shutdown
- Cold Reboot
- GRUB Commandline opened
- Somehow kept rebooting and got into Ubuntu
- ??? (Win. Bootloader somehow automatically moved back up to top priority boot)
- PROFIT! (Everything fixed!)

Sorry I don't have more details for anyone having this problem.

SOLVED!