# not detecting the windows after partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 in dual-boot with Windows 10.

My `C:` drive in Windows 10 had 120G and I divided it to three drives (the Windows drive 50G, a drive for swap 17G and another drive). Before I did this, the Linux installation detected my Windows, but afterwards it didn't.

So now I can't see any of my partition when I am selecting the "Something Else" option in the installer. Windows is still booting and running fine. 
My laptop is a *hp probook450 g2* and I don't know how to disable UEFI.

Comment: Post this from terminal in live installer. `sudo parted -l` Also similar model? http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert by any means but I did have some problems with dual-booting a UEFI laptop which I finally resolved.

The latest installers are able to cope with UEFI disks and secure boot so in my view trying to disable UEFI is an unnecessary complication.

I found these two articles very worthwhile the study when I was doing my dual boot and  commend them to you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[Allowing boot of Ubuntu on a Acer Aspire v5-531 with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519610/allowing-boot-of-ubuntu-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-531-with-uefi)

I think they supersede a lot of commonly available advice because boot processes compatible with UEFI and secure boot have now been developed.

Good luck with them. If you come across more difficulties I'd be happy to try to help but with the heads-up that, as I said above, I'm no expert!