# Unable to install Ubuntu in Acer Predator Helios 300

Tags: boot, system-installation

During the last stage of installation my laptop is getting freeze and I'm not able to restart my system in order to install ubuntu. I'm getting this type of error:

[image: error messages on boot screen]

What are the steps that I should take to install Ubuntu in Acer Predator Helios 300?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/519610/allowing-boot-of-ubuntu-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-531-with-uefi

Comment: No its not helping, I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Is your computer dual boot?